# Acessing an original array from another class C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I'm working on a game where I have a class for my character and a class to handle the GUI.

In the character class I have an array of structs which hold data about the character's skills. I'm trying to access this array with the GUI class, to display the info about the skills.

To use one class in another one, I would need to initialize a new instance of it, which resets the values I might have changed in the meantime. Is there any way to pass that array? I can't make it read-only because I still have to change the array. The array is also not being modified in the GUI class.

Also, in the future I'm going to save this data in XML or in a database. Is it a possibility to get the info out of these files every time I need them? Instead of having to work with passing the array on and things like that. Or even calculate everything server side?

Thanks in advance!

Simon.

Comment: provide simplified code you have, it is too much abstract this way to give a meaningful answer. how do you declare the classes and how do you access them? what do they look like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have one array for the entire program, simply make the array `public static`. If you want to have that class be able to access the array inside characters that you pass it, make the array `public` or make a property for which the `get` part is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is not static (which seems not), you can define the array as a property of the `character` class and have access to array like:  `myCharacter.Skills`.

If you want to have access to your Entities (`character` class in your case) in multiple projects, you can implement a multi-layer architecture and define your entities in an isolated class library and reference this class library in any project that should have access to you entities.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid. The array needs to be changed in the character class, it calculates some things like levels, etc.

Comment: Then define custom properties for that data that need to be passed to your GUI. even maybe in a separate class for separation. For example define `Level` property and calculate it with your (now `private`) array, and then access it in your UI like `myCharacter.Level`

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to pass data in to a GUI directly, if it can be avoided. I would suggest using the Model-View-Controller pattern or the Model-View-Presenter pattern. If you're using WPF, you should look at Model-View-ViewModel.

Basically, you want a class whose responsibility is to maintain the data (whether it be stored in memory, a database, etc.), the view needs some abstraction from the data, and also a means to format it for presentation/display purposes (Presenter).

Here is a brief overview : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, thanks :) Though, I'm obviously doing it in the wrong way. So instead of the original, I would need to pass a copy? Is this also needed when I don't change any values in the GUI class?

Comment: You want to construct a Presenter instance, and pass that in to the constructor of your GUI. Any manipulations you want to enact on your data structures via the GUI would be done through the presenter. The presenter would provide public methods for specific actions that you want your GUI to be allowed to make. Rather than exposing the entire datastructure to the GUI, you'd have a Presenter.IncreaseStrength() method, for example.

Comment: I would find some examples of MVP in action. What you're trying to do is a pretty common thing for all GUI applications. Having a public static reference that is accessible to the entire executable assembly is a really bad practice. You're allowing any consumer to manipulate the data, rather than encapsulating it. The View (Form)'s shouldn't have the right to access the data, since a view should have little to no logic.

Comment: I see. So this is a security measure? Well, going to look it up :) Thanks! But for the moment I'm sticking with Seth's answer, Just need to get a prototype up ;)

Comment: Yes, you are protecting your data from unwanted manipulation. If someone were to use or extend your classes and you leave the data wide open, you can't really restrict them from doing things. I understand that you may be doing a prototype, and Seth's answer does work, but I'm trying to encourage good design practices to ye :).

Answer (score 1):

Either your character should be static or you should store a reference to your character (or a `List<Character>`  in your GUI class.  Furthermore, it would probably be best not to provide direct access to the list of structs that maintains your character information if you just want to print.  Your Character class should provide a method(s) for printing out the character data, i.e. `character.printCharacterInfo()` which will return a string, or maybe `character.getCharacterInfo` which will return the struct containing the data for that character which your GUI class can use to do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using structs in Array?

This way, you may be accessing the copies, they are not reference types in C#.

```
public struct PointStruct
    {
        public int X;
    }

    public class PointClass
    {
        public int X;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestStruct()
    {
        var structArray = new PointStruct[1];
        var classArray = new PointClass[1];

        int x;

        x = structArray[0].X;

        try
        {
            x = classArray[0].X;
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        classArray[0] = new PointClass();

        // It's now ok
        x = classArray[0].X;

        var point1 = structArray[0];
        var point2 = classArray[0];

        point1.X = 1;
        point2.X = 1;

        Assert.IsTrue(point2.X == 1);
        Assert.IsFalse (structArray[0].X == 1);

        structArray[0].X = 1;
        Assert.IsTrue(structArray[0].X == 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had googled my problem and was take here, I used the answers here to do mine.

When a user clicked a button I wanted the code to be carried out in another class called Logic. My main class was called MainWindow.

I had an array of colors linked to two rectangles in MainWindow. In order to be able to access the values stored in the array i simply had to do this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

 Rectangle[] choice;
 SolidColorBrush black;
Became
 public static Rectangle[] choice;
 public static SolidColorBrush black;

}
```

in my Logic class to access it I had to do this.

```
MainWindow.choice[0].Fill = MainWindow.black;
```

Hope that helps anyone at all.